# rx-java: Subscribe to Observable in onHandleIntent of IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice, retrofit, rx-java

I faced following issue which didn't manage to fix:

I have an IntentService which performs some job in onHandleIntent method. Beside of some common things in this method I have to make a request to the backend and send required information. As everyone knows, onHandleIntent method works in its own thread and stops at the moment when it performed the last command. In case of some async operations - result might be lost, so google suggests to use only sync operations inside of this method.

And here is my problem, i'm not using subscribeOn and observeOn, but looks like my methods work in sep. threads and that's not safe for me.

Here is the body of my onHandleIntent method with Retrofit (with rx.Observable) call:

```
Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent | started");

...

getAPI().addItem(item).timeout(AppConfig.NETWORK_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).doOnNext(new Action1<Response<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Response<String> response) {
           //some job
          Log.d(TAG, "doOnNext || call");
        }
    }).retryWhen(new RetryWithSessionRefresh()).subscribe(new Observer<Response<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Observer onCompleted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Observer onError");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Response<String> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Observer onNext");
            }
        });

...

Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent | finished");
```

Retrofit method getItem(item) is:

```
 rx.Observable<Response<String>> addItem(@Body ArrayList<Item> item);
```

And finally the result is:

- 11-20 00:49:03.512  onHandleIntent | started
- 11-20 00:49:03.517  onHandleIntent | finished
- 11-20 00:49:04.549  doOnNext || call
- 11-20 00:49:04.549  Observer onNext
- 11-20 00:49:04.550  Observer onCompleted

So, the question is how to make it work in the same thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always change the Http Executer used by your `RestAdapter` instance to be synchronous.  Retrofit uses the Http Executer internally to schedule the `Observable`.  That would allow you to start the flow on the thread that you subscribe on.  That would also mean that you can't use this `RestAdapter` else where if you're not going to provide your own `Thread` like the IntentService those.

```
Executor immediateExecuter = new Executor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Runnable command) {
                command.run();
            }
        };

... new RestAdapter.Builder().setExecutors(immediateExecuter, null).build();
```

I think you could also take advantage of the tools that RxJava provides you to get around this issue.  You could use `toBlocking` which turns your `Observable` into a `BlockingObservable`.  This would allow you to wait for your stream to complete fully before continuing code execution.  One thing to take into consideration is that you'll have to wrap your whole flow with a try/catch block to handle exceptions since now uncaught exceptions in the flow will be thrown.  I guess you could say that this will turn your stream into a big imperative statement.

```
try {
    getAPI().addItem(item).timeout(AppConfig.NETWORK_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).doOnNext(new Action1<Response<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Response<String> response) {
               //some job
              Log.d(TAG, "doOnNext || call");
            }
        })
        .retryWhen(new RetryWithSessionRefresh())
        .toBlocking()
        .forEach(new Action1<Response<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Response<String> s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Observer onNext");
                }
        });
} catch (WhatEverExceptionsYourStreamMightThrow e) {
  // Handle error here
}

...

Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent | finished");
```

I think it's important to note that this second solution would always involve 2 threads every time the IntentService is run.  One Thread would be used by Retrofit and the other would be the IntentService itself.

Comment: Miguel, thanks a lot! Just a small question: if I setup my RestAdapter instance to be synchronous - will subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) change my operation from synchronous to asynchronous?

Comment: Just tested it! It works like a charm! So it looks quite good to make RestAdapter synchronous and whenever you need to use asynchronous request just to use subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())! Thank you again!

Comment: Yes that should be the case.  Have you given it a shot?

Comment: Hi, Can I also ask what thread is the Retrofit Call run on ? I don't quite get the part that Retrofit spins out another Thread, I reckon it just uses the caller Thread which is the IntentService thread if we don't set any Scheduler, so theoretically they are in the same thread. Can you please elaborate more on "Retrofit uses Http Executer internally to schedule the Observable" ?

Comment: @WenChao by using the reactive style signature prior to retrofit 2 by default retrofit would turn your request into an async one using it's own defined executor if you didn't override it when building your RestAdapter instance.  Take a look at the default executor used https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.9.0/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/Platform.java#L136

Comment: Thanks for that ! was looking at the 2.0 version and couldn't figure out why :)